# Finding annual dates with Rails 3.1 ActiveRecord Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building a Rails 3.1 project in which one of my models contains a birthday attribute. I have been trying to find a query that essentially finds all users with a birthday within a certain range. The problem is that this part of the application doesn't really care about the year of birth, just the month and day. Unfortunately, Google has not been of much help on this one.

Does anyone know how to query for all records whose birthday attribute "has an anniversary" within a certain date range? I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
M.where(%q{
    array[extract(month from d)::int, extract(day from d)::int] between array[?, ?] and array[?, ?]
}, lower_month, lower_day, upper_month, upper_day)
```

where `M` is your model, `bday` is the birthday column, and the upper and lower variables hold the month and day boundaries. You could also use [INTERSECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html):

```
M.find_by_sql([%q{
    select * from ms where array[? ,?] <= array[extract(month from bday)::int, extract(day from bday)::int]
    intersect
    select * from ms where array[?, ?] >= array[extract(month from bday)::int, extract(day from bday)::int]
}, lower_month, lower_day, upper_month, upper_day])
```

Yet another version would use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
M.where(
    "to_char(bday, 'MM') || to_char(bday, 'DD') between ? and ?",
    '%2.2d%2.2d' % [lower_month, lower_day],
    '%2.2d%2.2d' % [upper_month, upper_day]
)
```

You could get the same results with a big ugly pile of CASE statements too (so that you'd only consider the day-of-month at the month boundaries) but the the intersection is (IMO) cleaner and easier to read. Using the (PostgreSQL) arrays allows you to compare the month/day pairs with each other as single units rather than separately.

Comment: Great. I was only testing with a couple of records and the previous query seemed to work, but now I can see where that one would give incorrect results. Thank you so much! I'm no SQL guru, so I always need help on this sort of thing.

Comment: @Andrew: I originally made the same mistake you probably did and I'm supposed to be good at this stuff :) Inferring a query based on a limited data set is fraught with danger and that's why we check each other's work.

Comment: Will this work across months (e.g., 10/31-11/4)? For example, when I run the first part of the query for 10/31, it only picks up birthdays happening on or after the 31st (i.e., only months with 31 days and not 11/1, 11/2, etc.). So my intersection keeps turning up '0' even though I have birthdays in between that time range. Also, I get a 'wrong number of arguments (5 for 2)' from the Rails console when I load the query as written in this answer.

Comment: @JHo: There were some missing brackets in the `find_by_sql` call, sorry about that. I think you might be right about the edge case, I'll get my head around this again and get back to you tonight.

Comment: @JHo: You were right, thanks for pointing out the brain damage. I've updated with some better options with, hopefully, less brain damage.

Comment: @mu That last one 'to_char' works perfectly. Thank you. A far simpler and more flexible way to find coming birthdays and anniversaries with in Rails than any other approach I have found.

Comment: @JHo: I like the `to_char` one too, that's just another "[ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) dates are the best because they sort properly as strings" trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are various date-functions in sql. Some of which just pull out the day/month (independent of the year).  I'm pretty sure there's one that just returns the "day of the year" (ie 1 to 365) (and if there isn't you could write one) - in which case you could use that and grab all rows that have their day-of-year within a small range of the one you've got in your hand right now.

Comment: You could run into leap year issues with `extract(doy from bday)` though, probably safest to consider the day-of-month and month separately.

Comment: Awesome. I ended up using extract and considering month and day of month separately, and it's working like a charm!

Comment: @Andrew: Are you sure it is working like a charm? You should only look at the day-of-month when then month number is equal to the upper or lower month (I admit that I made that mistake in my original attempt).